# Is root urls.py means config/urls.py in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am super newbie on programming using django as a backend.
I am making a login function with JWT (using simplejwt).

Trying to make it while watching simplejwt official doc,
I don't know what is root urls.py means in doc.

[image]

In the first line of the above picture.

"root urls.py" === config/urls.py ??

Am I right...?

Comment: `root urls.py` means one that belongs to the Main project's `urls.py` the one you created with `django-admin startproject projectname`. not from the `apps or modules`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just an example Best way for you is to do this way:

Use django terminal to create new `authentication` app.

After that just register your urls in main urls.py in project urls.py.

Incase you don't need any customization of JWT just encorporate your those urls
in authentication urls file and hit your urls.

So your urls will be like this:

```
 path('login/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
```

`localhost:8000/api/login`